# Python Decimal Library is Imprecise?

Tags: python, decimal, precision, floating-accuracy

I'm reading up on the Python Decimal module. I have a need to make a large number of precise calculations, often with lots of decimal places, where being off by a small amount adds up over time. Enter the Decimal library.

Step 1: Read [the intro to Decimal library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) (added bold):

> - **Decimal numbers can be represented exactly**.  In contrast, numbers like 1.1 and 2.2 do not have exact representations in binary floating point.  End users typically would not expect `1.1 + 2.2` to display as 3.3000000000000003 as it does with binary floating point.

Step 2: Plug a decimal in to Python. This seems to be imprecise - off by a very similar margin as the float calculation.

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> 1.1 + 2.2
3.3000000000000003
>>> Decimal(3.3)
Decimal('3.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875')
```

What's going on?

Comment: **Read the documentation carefully**. What do you *think* happens when you pass a `float` object to the `Decimal` constructor?

Comment: You may need algorithms to mitigate precision errors.

Comment: @Juanpa thanks, I realized my mistake

Comment: The Decimal format can only calculate exactly results that are decimal results, that is, those that are expressible as decimal numerals. If you exceed the number of digits it supports or that you have set it for, or if you perform any calculation that has a result not expressible as decimal numeral, such as the esoteric 1/3, then its precision behaves like other numeric formats.

Answer (score 3):

[Per the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html):

> Construction from an integer or a float performs an exact conversion of the value of that integer or float.

The exact value of the `float` literal `3.3` is not *3.3* = 33/10, but the binary approximation 3715469692580659 / 2<sup>50</sup>, whose exact value is what you see in your screenshot.  If this is not what you want, then pass a `str` instead of a `float` to the constructor.

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> Decimal(3.3)
Decimal('3.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875')
>>> Decimal('3.3')
Decimal('3.3')
```

Also remember while that `Decimal` is exact at representing *base-ten* fractions like 1/10, 1/100, or 1/1000, other fractions are approximated (albeit to more precision than `float`).

```
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(3)
Decimal('0.3333333333333333333333333333')
>>> _ * 3
Decimal('0.9999999999999999999999999999')
```

If this is an issue for you, then use the `Fraction` class instead of `Decimal`.

```
>>> from fractions import *
>>> Fraction(1) / Fraction(3)
Fraction(1, 3)
>>> _ * 3
Fraction(1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Especially the part about the Fraction module. I didn't realize that was out there. Decimal will still work for me. I don't need perfect precision, but I definitely needed more than Float was giving me.